# User Self registration WSO2 IS tenant admin necessary?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

[Reference](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Self+Sign+Up+and+Account+Confirmation) 
Is it necessary to provide the tenant-admin-UserName & tenant-admin-Password to registerUser()..
Can't it be handled at the super tenant level ?

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://services.mgt.identity.carbon.wso2.org" xmlns:xsd="http://dto.mgt.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:registerUser>
         <ser:userName>testSelfUser</ser:userName>
         <ser:password>testSelfUser</ser:password>
         <ser:claims>
            <xsd:claimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/country</xsd:claimUri>
            <xsd:claimValue>usa</xsd:claimValue>
         </ser:claims>
         <ser:claims>
            <xsd:claimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress</xsd:claimUri>
            <xsd:claimValue>testSelfUser@email.com</xsd:claimValue>
         </ser:claims>
         <ser:profileName>default</ser:profileName>
         <ser:tenantDomain>mytenant.com</ser:tenantDomain>
      </ser:registerUser>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

> UserInformationRecoveryService

As authorization header do we have to pass in the **admin@mytenant.com:************

Comment: Please explain your question further.

Comment: @Bhathiya , updated with what I am trying to do..